# Can I pass just the keyword name of a keyword argument in a Python wrapper function?

Tags: python

I have had a dig around in the questions and I can't seem to get this working.

Basically I want to pass an optional keyword to "wrapperfunc" so that I get the relative data out from the "load_data" function that it calls. I want the argument to wrapperfunc to specify what method is done on the data.

I am sure this is a case of unpacking the arguments in the correct way?

```
import numpy as np

def load_data(remove_smallest = None, remove_largest = None):
    data = np.arange(0,100,1)
    if remove_smallest != None:
        data = data[remove_smallest::]
    elif remove_largest != None:
        data = data[0:(100-remove_largest)]
    else:
        data = data
    return print(data)
    

def wrapperfunc(**args):
    val = [10, 20, 30]
    for v in val:
        load_data(args = v)


wrapperfunc(remove_smallest)
wrapperfunc(remove_largest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`**kwargs` are just dicts of `str: object`, so you can have the wrapper take a *key name*, create a dict out of that, and using that to call the wrapped function:

```py
def wrapperfunc(key):
    val = [10, 20, 30]
    for v in val:
        load_data(**{key: v})


wrapperfunc('remove_smallest')
wrapperfunc('remove_largest')
```

Answer (score -1):

No, keyword arguments are purely *syntactic*, though the name and value are collected in a `dict` if the name does not correspond to a named parameter.

The closest you can do is pass a `str` value, then pass an unpacked `dict` to `load_data`.

```
def wrapper(arg):
    val = [10, 20, 30]
    for v in val:
        load_data(**{arg: v})

wrapper('remove_smallest')
```

Comment: "No, keyword arguments are purely syntactic"  named arguments are absolutely not "purely syntactic". Maybe you meant "symbolic", as in they're symbols? "Purely syntactic" would mean they don't exist at runtime, which they most definitely do.

Comment: Yes, they are. It's a syntactic way of assigning a value to a parameter by name rather than by position, or to populate a `**` parameter. Passing an explicitly unpacked dictionary is *another* way to specify values by name.

Comment: That's not what "purely syntactic" means. And keyword arguments [are not necessarily passed in as a dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION_KW).

Comment: Referring to (CPython-specific) byte codes bypasses the issue of syntax completely. I'm talking about Python source code.